# How to perform file save using chrome app filesystem api?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

I'm going through the Chrome App [tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage#filesystem), and am stuck trying to save a file using the filesystem API.

As I understand the description, I should be able to open and read a file, then use the same FileEntry to create a writable FileEntry object and replace the file contents.

I am able to choose and read the file contents, and the overwrite seems to *almost* work.  Console output leads me to believe the file was written, but the contents don't actually change. Here's my code and output;

**manifest.json**;

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "angular toots",
  "version": "1",
  "icons": { "128": "icon_128.png" },
  "app": { "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] } },
  "permissions": [{"fileSystem": ["write", "retainEntries", "directory"]}], 
  "minimum_chrome_version": "28"
}
```

**index.html**;

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl" >
    <div>
        <form name="fileForm">
            <button ng-click="onLoad()">Load</button>
            <button ng-click="onSave()">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

**app.js**;

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.chosenFileEntry = null;

    $scope.onLoad = function(e) {
        chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openFile'}, function(fileEntry) {
            $scope.chosenFileEntry = fileEntry;
            console.log($scope.chosenFileEntry);
            fileEntry.file(function(file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onerror = function(e){console.log('error 1');};
                reader.onloadend = function(loadEvent) {
                    console.log(loadEvent.target.result);
                };
                reader.readAsText(file);
            }, function(e){console.log('error 2');});
        });
    };

    $scope.onSave = function(e){
        console.log('onSave');
        console.log($scope.chosenFileEntry);
        chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry($scope.chosenFileEntry, function(writableFileEntry) {
            writableFileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                writer.onerror = function(e){console.log('error 1');};
                writer.onwriteend = function(e){console.log('written');};
                console.log('writing');
                $scope.chosenFileEntry.file(function(file) {
                    writer.write(file);
                });
            }, function(e){console.log('error 2');});
        });
    };
});
```

**c:\Users\rooster\Desktop\foo.txt**

```
Some Text
```

When I click Load, then Save, I get this in the console;

```
> FileEntry {isFile: true, isDirectory: false, name: "foo.txt", fullPath: "/foo.txt", filesystem: DOMFileSystem}
Some Text
onSave
> FileEntry {isFile: true, isDirectory: false, name: "foo.txt", fullPath: "/foo.txt", filesystem: DOMFileSystem}
writing
written
```

However, the contents of the target file are unchanged.

I do notice the FileEntry **fullPath** attribute isn't really the file's full path.  Attempting to modify that attribute doesn't seem to have any effect, i.e. it can't be changed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`chrome.fileSystem API`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem). You will need to ask the user at least once where to save the file, but then you can retain the entry to write again to the same file/folder.

Bring up a prompt using `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({'type': "openDirectory"})` to ask the user to choose a directory, but I can't find a way of saving to that directory.

Declare permission for the `fileSystem API`:

```
"permissions": [
{"fileSystem": ["write", "retainEntries", "directory"]}
]
```

Then, by using [HTML FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/), you can create files in the directory:

```
dirEntry.getFile(
"test.txt",
{create: true}, // add "exclusive: true" to prevent overwrite
function(fileEntry) { /* write here */ },
function(e) { console.error(e) }
);
```